# How to insert quotations in Org tables?

Tags: org-mode, org-table

In org mode, how does one insert a quotation in a table cell?

I know that `#+BEGIN_QUOTE` ... `#+END_QUOTE` is the way to go outside a table, but I can't find a way to use it *inside* a table cell.

Comment: [Table cells](https://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-syntax.html#Table_Cells) can contain strings (with some restrictions): that's all they can contain.  Why do you need a quote block?

Comment: I'm working on a dialog editor and currently writting the documentation. I'd like to have a cheatsheet (table) of all the commands you have in that dialog editor, with an example. The triggers are either embbeded in a line of dialog, or alone one their line. When they're in a dialog line a quote makes it easier to understand the situation.

Comment: I don't know if [table.el tables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Text-Based-Tables.html) would be more appropriate for that: Org mode has some support for exporting them IIRC, but not much more than that. See [Packages that Org cooperates with](https://orgmode.org/manual/Cooperation.html#Cooperation)

Comment: Are you planning to export the cheatsheet table into another file type like pdf, markdown, html, etc? If so you could store the unformatted quote text in a column and then pass the table data to src block to do the formatting when exporting.

Comment: wait wait @Melioratus. Sorry but I don't understand your suggestion. Could you show me some links or example or something please? Thanks for the help.